# How can I easily add others to update my G Suite App listing?

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I've looked all over the admin console, but can't find where to add other users so that they can edit our listing. Can you please provide a URL/link to where I should navigate?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [support page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172176?hl=en). You can:

- assign [pre-built roles](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986) for performing common business tasks
- assign [custom roles](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2406043) you create for your organization
- assign more than one role to a user to grant all privileges in those roles

Be noted that you must be signed in as a [super administrator](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2405986#super_admin) for this task.

> The user typically gets their new privileges within a few minutes. However, it can take up to 24 hours. When they sign in to their account, they arrive at the Admin console dashboard. Here they see the controls allowed by their privileges.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing this article! This article is for customers of G Suite accounts, and not for developers building for G Suite marketplace. I'm specifically looking for how add administrators to my app listing in the G Suite marketplace as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to navigate to this URL while logged in as the app project owner:

https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=(add your project ID)

And assign roles to different users or groups.

Answer (score 0):

you can use group publishing on the gsuite marketplace:

> Set up Group Publishing
>   You can share ownership of your items in Google Chrome Web Store with other developers by setting up group publishing. With group publishing, you can add developers to a Google Group, who can then act on your behalf. They'll have access to all the items you own and can make any changes to them that you can make.

https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing

(each member of the group should pay the 5$ developer fee though.)

You can configure the group from your webstore dashboard.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard